# FPV camera not working

Tags: first-person-view, fpv-cameras

I've bought the following two items:

- https://droneshop.nl/emax-transporter-fpv-bril
- https://droneshop.nl/star-power-vm275t-5g8-25mw-48-channel-vtx-with-osd

Both are 5.8ghz 48-channel. They both support NTSC and PAL.

I'm only getting video "noise", in the form of random horizontal lines mixed with snow. I am certian that I'm at the right channel, as when I mismatch channels I see "traditional" snow. See https://i.imgur.com/RdtNHhA.mp4.

I've hooked up the camera to a (chinese) CC3D, to the main port. The main port is configured for telemetry at a baud rate of 57600.

The manufacturer indicated the camera could be broken. I already received a different camera from the store (same model), but seem to be getting the same problem.

How do I continue to diagnose and fix this problem?

Mismatched channel giving traditional snow:
[image]
Matching channels. I'd expect this to work, but it gives this:
[image]
Connections couldn't be simpler.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's happened here is that the camera and flight controller are from different generations of gear, and although the plug fits, they aren't designed to work together like this.

All-In-One Cameras with 4 wires tend to have two for power, and one wire to send the raw video out to the flight controller, which overlays an On Screen Display (OSD) and sends it back on the last wire, where it goes to the video transmitter.

The CC3D is an old flight controller, from the days before OSDs were common. The ports are digital UARTs, not for an analog TV signal. They're for digital receivers, GPS modules, etc.

I think that to get this to work you should find the manuals for the CC3D and the camera. Check exactly what that port on the CC3D does. If it's what I think it is, check which pins on the port are power, and make sure they match up with the power wires on the camera. Then disconnect the video wires from the CC3D and connect them to each other.

Also, the lens cap is on in the last photo. I don't think that's the problem as I can see it in another photo, but that's actually the most common reason for 'my screen just shows black' questions ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This was indeed the problem. I assumed the OSD to be added in the camera module and those two wires to be UART...
When connecting those two wires it indeed works, so I ordered a separate OSD module. This kind of trouble is what I get for trying to build a cheap drone, I guess...

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg - Oh, you get the same kind of issues with expensive drones too! Every time one company adds a feature, it causes compatibility issues with everything else.